# How would I go about matching like this

Tags: elixir

I've got a function that takes a collection which is a list of id/item tuples and is supposed to replace an item given and id and new item.

```
def update_item(collection, id, new_item) do
  Enum.map(collection, fn
    ({ ^id, _ }) -> { id, new_item }
    (entry) -> entry
  end)
end
```

This fails with a `CompileError` and message `unbound variable ^id`. How can I do this? Is there a good way to do this or should I go about this another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use guard:

```
iex(1)> collection = [a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, b: 4]

iex(2)> id = :b
iex(3)> new_item = 5

iex(4)> Enum.map(collection, fn
          ({coll_id, _ }) when coll_id == id -> { id, new_item }
          (entry) -> entry
        end)
[a: 1, b: 5, c: 3, b: 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using classic tail recursion you can define `update_item` like this:

```rb
def update_item([{ id, _} | t], id, new_item) do
    [{id, new_item} | update_item(t, id, new_item)]
end

def update_item([h | t], id, new_item) do
    [h | update_item(t, id, new_item)]
end

def update_item([], _, _) do
    []
end

update_item([{4, 56}, {1, 44}, {1, 33}, {2, 55}], 1, 23)
# => [{4, 56}, {1, 23}, {1, 23}, {2, 55}]
```

the first definition replaces the first item if its id matches the input, while the second simply recurses without replacing the item. The third method is a stop condition for an empty list.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It certainly works, but the answer I accepted is shorter and more what I was looking for.